# Windows authentication not working in IIS

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, authentication

I am using .net 4.5 and mvc4.I want to get the name of currently logged in machine user.
It is working locally but when I deployed on IIS it's not working.If I enable anonymous authentication then it's working but site asks for login every time which is not required.
Any idea that this should work without logging in everytime?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to leave enabled APS.NET-Impersonation and Windows Authentication, and disable all the other authentication methods. Also make sure that Impersonation is not enabled in your web.config (`<identity impersonate="false" />`). [More info here (See figure 3)](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/understanding-iis-70-authentication)

How do you access the user info?  The HttpContext should give you the currently logged in user, when the IIS authentication methods are properly setup.

`Dim identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(False)
Dim httpContextIndentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
Response.Write(String.Format("<p>Running as: {0}</p>", identity.Name))
Response.Write(String.Format("<p>User identity: {0}</p>", httpContextIndentity.Name))`

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous authentication mist be disabled, Windows authentication must be enabled. Follow last post in [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1983202.aspx?ASP%20NET%204%200%20and%20LDAP%20Authentication%20on%20IIS%206) and check if your setup is correct.